# adds the number before entering grade

Tags: java

i used scanner in java and when i choose between 1-gradebook and 2- exclude failing grades) it needs two input instead of one, and when the loop starts it adds the second input to the sum

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BarrogoMidtermExam {


    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String Myname;
        Scanner mname=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter name: ");
        Myname=mname.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Gradebook Type(1- Gradebook, 2-Exclude Failing grades): ");
        Scanner gradebook = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i=gradebook.nextInt();

        if (i==1)
        {

            Scanner grade=new Scanner(System.in);
            int average=0;
            int total=0;
            int g = grade.nextInt();
            String outputString = "";
            while (g !=0)
            {
                 outputString += g + " ";
                 total +=g;
                 average /= total;

                System.out.println("enter grade (enter 0 to stop entering grade):  ");
             g = grade.nextInt();

            }
            System.out.println(Myname);
          System.out.println("Entered Number:\t" + outputString);
          System.out.println("The Sum:\t\t" + total);
        }




    }
}
```

Comment: what's the problem

Comment: Don't create a new `Scanner` every time you need to do input.  Create **one** `Scanner` and use it **every time** you need input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when you are initializing `int g = grade.nextInt()` you are actually asking the user to enter a value, which is why your program "asks" twice before going into the loop where grades are entered and subsequently whatever value was assigned to `g` ends up being part of the average. You can modify your code as follows:

```
// Scanner grade=new Scanner(System.in);// no need to create another scanner 
int total=0;
int g = 0;
String outputString = "";
while(true) {  // Create an infinite loop
    System.out.println("enter grade (enter 0 to stop entering grade):  ");
    g = mname.nextInt();
    if(g == 0) { // Break from the infinite loop if the user entered 0
        break;
    }
    outputString += g + " ";
    total +=g;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you're asking but inside your if statement, you have this following code:

```
Scanner grade=new Scanner(System.in);
int g = grade.nextInt();
```

which means that your variable g is asking for an input from the user and then there's another one of this in your while loop that's **within** your if statement which is also asking the user to input some values for g.

You don't need multiple [Scanner](https://www.javatpoint.com/Scanner-class) on your program. One is enough. 
Besides from using a while loop, you may also use a for loop for your code like this:

```
int average=0;
int total=0;
int g;
String outputString = "";

// I'm asking the user how many grades do they want to enter
System.out.print("Enter the number of Grades you want in your Gradebook:");
int n = mname.nextInt();

for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
    System.out.println("Enter grade: ");
    g = mname.nextInt();
    outputString += g + " ";
    total +=g;
    average = total/n;
   }
System.out.println(Myname);
System.out.println("Entered Number:\t" + outputString);
System.out.println("The Sum:\t\t" + total);
```

Also, originally, you had:

```
average /= total;
```

this will always give you 0. So you'd have to divide your variable total to the number of grades n entered to get the average.

If you want this code in a while loop, the above reference is a good one, but I believe you'll need a counter to keep track of the number of grades being entered to get the average.